# How to properly prepare query in php using sprintf

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to add some data to the database using php. My code was as follows:

```
$wpdb->prepare ("UPDATE $table_name SET
                            state = ". $state .",
                            duration = ". $duration .",
                            only_for_facebook = ". $only_for_facebook .",
                            start_at_1 = " . $start_at_db_1 . ",
                            active_duration_1 = ". $active_duration_1 .",
                            repeat_daily_1 = ". $repeat_daily_1 .",
                            start_at_2 = ". $start_at_db_2 .",
                            active_duration_2 = ". $active_duration_2 .",
                            repeat_daily_2 = ". $repeat_daily_2 .",
                            start_at_3 = ". $start_at_db_3 .",
                            active_duration_3 = ". $active_duration_3 .",
                            repeat_daily_3 = ". $repeat_daily_3 .",
                            start_at_4 = ". $start_at_db_4 .",
                            active_duration_4 = ". $active_duration_4 .",
                            repeat_daily_4 = ". $repeat_daily_4 .",
                            added_time = now()"))
```

and that worked in the past. But for some reason it doesn't work anymore and I get an error as:

```
 2018/03/15 17:40:07 [error] 47449#47449: *530638 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare(), 1 passed in /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-content/plugins/boky/ajax/save-refresh.php on line 48 and exactly 2 expected in /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1222
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-content/plugins/boky/ajax/save-refresh.php(48): wpdb->prepare('UPDATE wp_refre...')
    #1 /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): saveRefreshData('')
    #2 /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
    #3 /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
    #4 /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(97): do_action('wp_ajax_save_re...')
    #5 {main}
      thrown in /var/www/clients/client12/web19/web/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1222
```

Thus I need to use `sprintf` placeholders and pass arguments in an array. I tried to do it as follows:

```
$state = $_POST["state"];                               // That is int (0 or 1)
$duration = $_POST["duration"];                         // That is int   
$only_for_facebook = $_POST["only_for_facebook"];       // That is int (0 or 1)

$start_at_1 = $_POST["start_at_1"];                     // That is timestamp
$start_at_db_1 = !empty($start_at_1) ? "'$start_at_1'" : "NULL";    // That is timestamp or NULL
$active_duration_1 = !empty($_POST["active_duration_1"]) ? $_POST["active_duration_1"] : "NULL"; // That is int or NULL
$repeat_daily_1 = $_POST["repeat_daily_1"];             // That is int (0 or 1)


$wpdb->prepare ("UPDATE $table_name SET
                        state = %d,
                        duration = %d,
                        only_for_facebook = %d,
                        start_at_1 = %s,
                        active_duration_1 = %d,
                        repeat_daily_1 = %d,
                        added_time = %s"),
                array(  $state,
                        $duration,
                        $only_for_facebook,
                        $start_at_db_1,
                        $active_duration_1,
                        $repeat_daily_1,
                        now())))
```

Here is how it looks like in database:

[image]

But it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Wait, are you using `prepare` and *still* injecting values directly into the query? You need to take another look at how `prepare` works.

Comment: `NOW()` is a MySQL function, not a PHP function. Pass that in directly instead of attempting to bind it.

Comment: Are you passing the result of the prepare call to `$wpdb->query`? See reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: @S.Dev Yes, yes.

Comment: You're still ***very vulnerable to SQL injection***, `prepare()` is not magic, you still need to bind your variables as parameters.

Comment: The proper way is to not use `sprintf`, period.